# Extract multiple integers from string and store as int

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I know that this will extract the number and store as int -

```
string inputData = "sometex10";

string  data = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(inputData, @"\d+").Value;
int  number1 = Convert.ToInt32(data);
```

I am trying to extract multiple numbers from a string eg- 10 + 2 + 3 and store these as separate integers.
            note : the amount of numbers the user will type in is unknow.
            Any suggestions much appreciated thanks

Comment: Use this http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split

Comment: How your integers positions in your string? Can you show an example input and output you want?

Comment: input - 10 + 2 - 5 ,       output - int 10, 2, 5;

Comment: From the "+", "-" in your input string, it _looks_ like you're writing a simple calculator or similar. In which case, you probably actually want a tokeniser that captures the operators as well, and then something to turn that into an expression tree? Just a thought.

Comment: yes thats correct, could you provide some more info, or some keywords to search on, thank you

Comment: Searching for "c# recursive descent parser example calculator" found some good examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a LINQ one-liner:

```
var numbers = Regex.Matches(inputData, @"\d+").Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToList();
```

Or use `ToArray()` if you prefer an array instead of a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
C# program that uses Regex.Split
```

Referencing : http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // String containing numbers.
    //
    string sentence = "10 cats, 20 dogs, 40 fish and 1 programmer.";
    //
    // Get all digit sequence as strings.
    //
    string[] digits = Regex.Split(sentence, @"\D+");
    //
    // Now we have each number string.
    //
    foreach (string value in digits)
    {
        //
        // Parse the value to get the number.
        //
        int number;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out number))
        {
             Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but how would I store the output as separate integers?

Comment: `int[] numbers = new int[digits.Length]; for(int index = 0; index < digits.Length; index++){ int number; if (int.TryParse(digits[index], out number) { numbers[index] = number; } }`

Comment: Thank you, the output from  Console.WriteLine(numbers); gives me - System.Int32[] ??

Comment: @peter.k Changed the Code to Console.WriteLine(number)

Comment: That's because `numbers` is an *array of integers* (`int[]`; the `[]` indicates that it is an array and the `int` in front of it specifies that every element in the array is an `int`). If you want *one* value out of it, you need to specify the index; starting at `0`. So the first number would be `numbers[0]`, the second number would be `numbers[1]` and so on. For more information about arrays see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9b9dty7d.aspx).

Comment: @Corak Thank you for attending and answering this promptly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
string inputData = "sometex10";
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(inputData, @"\d+"))
{
    numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(m.Value));
}
```

This will store the integers in the list `numbers`